# Translation UnityScript to C# : yield & transform.position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm actually working to translate a unity project originally in UnityScript to C#. I already have translated a good part of the project, but i'm confronted to some problems :

The first problem is linked with **yield** :

```
yield Attack();
yield;
```

I already replaced all the : `yield WaitForSeconds()` but I don't know how to replace this.

Secondly another problem with transform.position :

```
transform.eulerAngles.y += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speedIdleRotate;
transform.position.y = currentHeight;
```

Throw the error:

```
UnityEngine.Transform.eulerAngles is not a variable
UnityEngine.Transform.position is not a variable
```

It's seem that .y is not considered, but in js I'ts working fine. How to deal with that in C#?

Comment: Whats wrong with the yield? Does js have a usage for it? Because c# uses it to build enumerable collections.

Comment: @PokeRwOw Show your original JS code for that and your present C# code for `Attack()` and surrounding method of `yield`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JS,

```
yield; // this means that wait for one frame
```

In C#,

```
yield return null;
```

---

I am not 100% sure but for yield Attack();

It should be

```
yield return Attack();
```

---

For,

```
transform.eulerAngles.y += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speedIdleRotate;
```

Try this:

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3( transform.eulerAngles.x , transform.eulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speedIdleRotate , transform.eulerAngles.z);
```

---

For,

```
transform.position.y = currentHeight;
```

Try this:

```
transform.position =new Vector3(transform.position.x,currentHeight,transform.position.z);
```

Sorry if I have something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, all you said is working except for the yield return new Attack(). Throwing me the error following : Attack() is a method but is using as type.

Comment: I just replace yield return new Attack(); by yield return Attack(); and It's working !

Answer (score 0):

I would like to just copy the Cyclops [answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/12911/what-are-the-syntax-differences-in-c-and-javascrip.html) for yield statement.

**Yield in Unity C# versus Unity Javascript**

Although Unity's documentation does (briefly) cover the syntax differences in using Yield at Writing C# Scripts(Step 4), there is also a Unity Answer that covers [How do I Use Yield in C#](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/622/how-do-i-use-yield-in-c), which has a more detailed explanation. In addition, the answer by equalsequals has a link to a Coroutine Tutorial that is worth checking out.

**Unity's Yield has additional capabilities over .NET C# Yield**

The above paragraph covered the differences in Unity's C# versus Javascript syntax. However, I think that it's worth explaining that the behavior of Unity's Yield statement (in both C# and Javascript), has some additional features not in Microsoft's .Net C# behavior.

Basically, Unity has added the YieldInstruction (and child classes such as WaitForSeconds) to Yield. These classes give Yield the ability to temporarily pause the function, until a condition is met. If it has zero parameters, it pauses for a single frame. If it has a parameter of WaitForSeconds:

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds (2.0f); // pauses for 2 seconds.
```

then it pauses for some number of seconds. If the parameter is another Coroutine, then it pauses until that Coroutine finishes.

**

> Yield only works this way inside a Coroutine. To start a Coroutine in
>   C#, you use StartCoroutine, whereas it is automatically called in
>   Javascript.

**

**While for second question Answer** 
You need to keep in mind fundamental difference as above given link described. shortly I can tell that:

This is because you're coding in C#. In javascript the compiler lets you modify the conmponent values of transform.position, but in C# it doesn't - you have to make a whole new Vector3 and assign it in one operation.

In Javascript, the compiler basically 'hides' the fact that it is doing this for you behind the scenes.[more](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/19888/transformposition-error.html)